# Количество знаков после запятой при делении числа 2**128-1 на 2

Tags: python

Как разделить, в python, число 2*128-1 или ему подобное на 2, несколько раз до получения ответа типа 1.ххххххххх
Необходимо максимально точно отобразить все знаки после запятой
Пробовал разные варианты float и to fixed decimal

Внесу небольшую правку если число будет представлять из себя разность степеней двойки , 2 ** 128 - 2 ** 11 - 2 ** 6-1

Comment: Задача хороша. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## decimal

### Простая постановка задачи

Для точного представления дроби *(2<sup>p</sup> - 1) / 2<sup>p-1</sup>* нужно ровно *p* десятичных разрядов. Выставляем нужную точность и получаем результат:

```
import decimal

p = int(input())
with decimal.localcontext() as c:
    c.prec = p
    print(decimal.Decimal(2 ** p - 1) / 2 ** (p - 1))
```

> ```
> $ echo 10 | python dec.py
> 1.998046875
>
> $ echo 128 | python dec.py
> 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999941225282458885624601563173138887716109066722161395623924562414686079137027263641357421875
> ```

*p* разрядов точности достаточно, потому что *(2<sup>p</sup> - 1)·5<sup>p-1</sup> < 2<sup>p</sup>·5<sup>p-1</sup> < 2<sup>p</sup>·5<sup>p</sup> = 10<sup>p</sup>*. А для него как раз и нужно *p* разрядов.

### Усложним немного

Решим задачу для произвольного числа *n*. [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) вычисляет для целого положительного числа его длину в битах. Обозначим её за *p*. Тогда нам нужно вывести *n / 2<sup>p-1</sup>*, а требуемая точность равна *p*.

```
import decimal


def print_fraction(n):
    p = n.bit_length()
    with decimal.localcontext() as c:
        c.prec = p
        print(decimal.Decimal(n) / 2 ** (p - 1))


def parse_exp(w):
    return (-1 if w.startswith('-') else 1), abs(int(w))

    
print_fraction(sum(s * 2 ** p for s, p in map(parse_exp, input().split())))
```

> ```
> $ echo 10 -0 | python dec.py
> 1.998046875
>
> $ echo 10 -5 -0 | python dec.py
> 1.935546875
>
> $ echo 10 -8 | python dec.py
> 1.5
>
> $ echo 128 -0 | python dec.py
> 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999941225282458885624601563173138887716109066722161395623924562414686079137027263641357421875
>
> $ echo 128 -11 -6 -0 | python dec.py
> 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999875809021835625324783102984842469744138457983927028953352600382231685216538608074188232421875
> ```

## Целые

### Простая постановка задачи

Вместо деления *2<sup>p</sup> - 1* на *2<sup>p-1</sup>* умножим его на *5<sup>p-1</sup>*. Получится целое число, которое ровно в *10<sup>p-1</sup>* раз больше нужного ответа. Целое превратим в строку, вставим точку после первого знака и готово:

```
p = int(input())
s = str((2 ** p - 1) * (5 ** (p - 1)))
print(f'{s[0]}.{s[1:]}')
```

> ```
> $ echo 10 | python int.py
> 1.998046875
>
> $ echo 128 | python int.py
> 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999941225282458885624601563173138887716109066722161395623924562414686079137027263641357421875
> ```

### Усложним немного

Требуемая точность *p* вычисляется так же как и в случае c `decimal`. Затем делается умножение на *5<sup>p-1</sup>*, дальше всё аналогично:

```
def print_fraction(n):
    p = n.bit_length()
    s = str(n * (5 ** (p - 1)))
    print(f'{s[0]}.{s[1:]}')


def parse_exp(w):
    return (-1 if w.startswith('-') else 1), abs(int(w))

    
print_fraction(sum(s * 2 ** p for s, p in map(parse_exp, input().split())))
```

> ```
> $ echo 10 -0 | python int.py
> 1.998046875
>
> $ echo 10 -5 -0 | python int.py
> 1.935546875
>
> $ echo 10 -8 | python int.py
> 1.500000000
>
> $ echo 128 -0 | python int.py
> 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999941225282458885624601563173138887716109066722161395623924562414686079137027263641357421875
>
> $ echo 128 -11 -6 -0 | python int.py
> 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999875809021835625324783102984842469744138457983927028953352600382231685216538608074188232421875
> ```

**P.S.** Оба способа опираются на знание какой будет результат. В первом способе надо определить нужную точность. Во втором способе деление на степень двойки заменяется умножением на степень пятёрки. Эти приемчики не сработают, например, для *(3<sup>p</sup> - 1) / 3<sup>p-1</sup>*. А даже для таких дробей есть способ решить задачу без трюков, полностью автоматически. Но поля книги слишком узки.

Answer (score 4):

Это не так уж сложно с использованием длинной арифметики, имеющейся в Python для целых чисел.

Пусть степень n=4. Тогда `2^4-1 = 1111` в бинарном представлении, а нужный результат `1.111` - опять же в бинарном. В десятичном виде дробная часть выглядит как `0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 = 0.875`, а если часть до точки пока убрать, то `500+250+125`

Получается, что вам нужно взять число `t=10**(n-1)`, начальное значение `s=0`, и в цикле делить `t` пополам и прибавлять к `s`,а в конце вывести `s` в виде `f'1.{s}'`

```
def ppp(n, minus_set):
    t = 10**(n-1)
    s = 0
    for i in reversed(range(n-1)):
        t //= 2
        if not i in minus_set:
            s += t
    return f'1.{s}'

print(ppp(6,{2,4}))
```

> ```
> >>> 1.34375
> ```

Проверяем: `(64-16-4-1)/32 = 1.34375`

Comment: Внесу небольшую правку если число будет представлять из себя разность степеней двойки , 2 ** 128 - 2 ** 11 - 2 ** 6-1

Comment: Этого в вопросе не было, однако принцип не меняется, только для вычитаемых степеней двойки не нужно прибавлять текущее t к результату (например, 1.101b= 1 + 0.5  + 0.125)

Comment: @СергейНиколаевич Ну что, разобрались?